# Universal Time different from RTC time in timedatectl

Tags: 20.04, time, date, ntp

As you can see in below, my Universal Time different from RTC time. It has 5 seconds later. My current Date is also 5 seconds later than real time. How can I fix it. I don't want to install `ntpd` or any new packages. I want to fix it by `timesyncd`.

[image]

I also set `Servers` in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` .

Comment: Try “sudo hwclock --systohc” in a terminal. That should synchronise them